# ModX WayFinder wont display the list

Tags: templates, modx

I have installed wayfinder on my MODX Revolution 2.2.0-rc3 (using the package manager).
There are 2 published documents.
I put that in the main template:

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`0` ]]
```

But nothing happened, Any idea y?
Keep in mind that this is my first day in Modx.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know the docs say to call it like that, but try calling it uncached first, if not ensure your published documents are not 'hidden'

uncached:

```
[[!Wayfinder? &startId=`0` ]]
```

force it to show hidden

```
[[!Wayfinder? &startId=`0` &ignoreHidden=`0` ]]
```

I see you have posted another question regarding modx as well, have you tried the modx official & user support forums?  rtfm.modx.com